# How to read PSB file extension (Image - Photoshop) in Java?

Tags: java, photoshop

I'm trying to load the [Andromeda picture of Hubble](https://www.spacetelescope.org/images/heic1502a/). In NASA official site, the original image source has PSB extension because of its size. I have 20 GB of RAM to load this image in RAM (heap). How do I do this?

More importantly, how does the system load different image types (conditionals)?

Also, I was researching, and PSB format allows you to store images with a size larger than 2GB. On the other hand, conventional formats (JPG) do not allow a size like this.

Currently, I have this code to load a image with JPG extension in RAM.

#### Java

```
BufferedImage nasaImage = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Python's standard library isn't going to include functionality to read a PSB file.  So you're talking about a third party module.  I did some Googling, and immediately found this: https://pypi.org/project/psd-tools.  I think ImageMagick can read PSD files, and there is a Python binding for it called PythonMagick.

Answer (score 0):

I was googling and found several interesting options to resolve this problem. Among those is [twelvemokeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) that allows to extend the capabilities of ImageIO of Java, I tried it and it works as expected without needing to modify the code (because as I mentioned earlier it allows ImageIO to extend its capabilities). Finally, they did a great job in modularizing the extensions at the different image formats.

**Maven**

```
 <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-psd -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>imageio-psd</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Java**

The same code with the path of the PSB image.

```
BufferedImage nasaImage = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
```

Remember the problem of the size of the images, check [twelvemonkeys recommendation](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/398).